Error: unusual error updating your profile
When I try to edit my profile, it redirects to a new page with this weird message.
No VPN Connected
Happening on all sites, tested in askubuntu.com, Thanks to @Lino




I can reproduce that on Windows / latest Chrome. Weird.

Does this only happen on Stack Overflow, or does it happen also in other communities? Might be a network wide bug

Same issue. Tried few other sites and they all show the same error.

It does a strange POST during loading. Not sure what triggers that.

[UPDATE 2] Issue has been resolved. Thanks again for the report!
[UPDATE 1] Issue found. Fix being worked on. Will let folks know once it's been deployed.
Thanks for the report. Submitting an internal ticket now. Will keep folks posted.
